# Zend Studio: how to add Less CSS support to Zend Studio?

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio, less

I would like to add [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org) support including syntax highlighting and ability to create/edit `.less` files. How can I do this?

Zend Studio is built on Eclipse, so instruction on how to do this in Eclipse may also be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LESS CSS Support for Eclipse PDT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577637/less-css-support-for-eclipse-pdt)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, there is no plugin for LessCSS for the Eclipse platform. If you're using PHPStorm on the other hand, it comes bundled with a very neat LessCSS plugin. NetBeans also has a plugin you can download and install, but it needs a little bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

ZendStudio is based on eclipse. I asked the same question some time ago and got a real answer few days ago.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577637/less-css-support-for-eclipse-pdt/7966689#7966689